# How to pass a token without postman

Tags: python, android, flask, jwt, access-token

Im building an app in android using flask and jwt;
how do i pass a token to a route?
This is my login:

```
   @app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_user():
    user_info = request.get_json()
    user_obj = User.query.filter_by(username = user_info['username']).first()
    if user_obj is not None:
        if user_info['password'] == user_obj.password:
            token = create_access_token(identity = user_obj.username)
            return jsonify({'access_token':token})
```

and my protected route:

```
@app.route('/jwt/users', methods = ['GET'])
@jwt_required
def get_all_users():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify({"result": current_user})
```

Now how do i pass the token created in my login to the protected route without postman? Im using android studio as a client.

This is my app.config:

```
app.config['JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION'] = ['headers', 'query_string']
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'this-is-the-secret-key'
```

(will obv change secret key later)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the token as part of the `header` to your protected endpoint.

Look at the example [here](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basic_usage/)

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/protected
{
  "msg": "Missing Authorization Header"
}

$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
  -d '{"username":"test","password":"test"}' http://localhost:5000/login
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmcmVzaCI6dHJ1ZSwianRpIjoiZjhmNDlmMjUtNTQ4OS00NmRjLTkyOWUtZTU2Y2QxOGZhNzRlIiwidXNlcl9jbGFpbXMiOnt9LCJuYmYiOjE0NzQ0NzQ3OTEsImlhdCI6MTQ3NDQ3NDc5MSwiaWRlbnRpdHkiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiZXhwIjoxNDc0NDc1NjkxLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIn0.vCy0Sec61i9prcGIRRCbG8e9NV6_wFH2ICFgUGCLKpc"
}

$ export ACCESS="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmcmVzaCI6dHJ1ZSwianRpIjoiZjhmNDlmMjUtNTQ4OS00NmRjLTkyOWUtZTU2Y2QxOGZhNzRlIiwidXNlcl9jbGFpbXMiOnt9LCJuYmYiOjE0NzQ0NzQ3OTEsImlhdCI6MTQ3NDQ3NDc5MSwiaWRlbnRpdHkiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiZXhwIjoxNDc0NDc1NjkxLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIn0.vCy0Sec61i9prcGIRRCbG8e9NV6_wFH2ICFgUGCLKpc"

$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS" http://localhost:5000/protected
{
  "logged_in_as": "test"
}
```